# Tkinter Filenames with StringVar

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I have a problem setting a filename in a tkinter environment (python 3.2 on a raspberry). To specify what I mean, I will use my code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, StringVar
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from threading import Thread

class proc(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.root=tkinter.Tk()
        self.labelstring = StringVar()
        self.labelstring.set('Foo')

        self.path = StringVar()
        self.path.set('cold.jpg')

        canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=888, height=600)
        canvas.pack()

        im = Image.open(self.path) #<-- does not work
        canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=canvas.image, anchor='nw')

        label = tkinter.Label(self.root,textvariable=self.labelstring)
        label.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()


app = proc()
app.start()


for i in range(0, 10):
    time.sleep(5)
    proc.labelstring.set(i)
```

The part where I change the label `labelstring.set(i)` works fine, but what does not work is sending a filename via `path.set('image.jpg')`. I konw, the filetype is not a path this way, it is a tkinter.StringVar Object... I did not find a good way to make it a path variable.

At the end of the day

```
im = Image.open(self.path)
canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=canvas.image, anchor='nw')
```

cannot be called with previously define `self.path.set('image.jpg')`. I want to maybe have a list of xy pics and do `path.set(piclist[i])` to change the image in the tkinter.canvas.

Comment: What does "not working" mean in the sentence "what does not work is sending a filename". Do you get errors? Does the wrong thing get sent? Does nothing get sent?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you want to achieve, and why use Threads here. Your code  has some inconsistencies, missing import statements, etc. Thus, I simplified it so that I can run it and just concentrate on the line you had indicated. The simplified version is:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, StringVar, Label
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from threading import Thread

class proc():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
       # Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        self.root=Tk()
        self.labelstring = StringVar()
        self.labelstring.set('Foo')

        self.path = StringVar()
        self.path.set('empty.gif')

        canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=888, height=600)
        canvas.pack()

        im = Image.open(self.path.get()) #<-- does not work
        canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
        canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=canvas.image, anchor='nw')

        label = Label(self.root,textvariable=self.labelstring)
        label.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()


app = proc()
app.run()
```

Concentrating on the line which does not work, in your example you have:

```
im = Image.open(self.path)
```

But you should be getting the file's path as follows (as in my example):

```
im = Image.open(self.path.get())
```

Comment: I used the threads to be able to update the tkinter canvas from "outside" - I want to for example change the image in the canvas every 10 seconds. Why do I need a .get() here inside the class for the filename, while I do not need it for the label (label = Label(self.root,textvariable=self.labelstring))

Comment: you can use tkinters `after` method to execute something every 10 seconds, no need for threads if you really want to use them for this. `Label`already knows that `self.labelstring` is an object of `StringVar()` and it knows to call its `get()` method. PIL does not know it. It just expects a path to an image file as a string.

Comment: On the thread thing: I read, I should use multiple threads when trying to update for example a canvas.

Comment: @xtlc: you almost never need to use threads to update a canvas. You only need threads if you need to run a function that takes longer than a few hundred milliseconds to complete. Updating a canvas rarely requires that much time.

Comment: I tried the solution above, but when I try to influence the image in the canvas I am ending up with nothing shown. I want to use 'app.path.set('second.jpg')' from outside the class to change the picture in the canvas...