# tkinter canvas update ImageTk.PhotoImage()

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, tkinter-canvas

This is a addon to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663058/tkinter-filenames-with-stringvar) and I read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29663058/tkinter-filenames-with-stringvar) aswell, but I don't know if a global variable is the perfect match for my problem.

I liked the solution Marcin proposed in my older thread a lot, I did however include the threading option, because I sometimes call functions within that canvas that need a lot of time (minutes ...) and I was told this should be done when these functions in the canvas take a lot of time ...

So here is my code so far:

```
class MyTkApp(Thread):
def __init__(self):
    Thread.__init__(self)

def run(self):
    self.root=tkinter.Tk()
    self.s = StringVar()
    self.s.set('Foo')

    self.path = StringVar()
    self.path.set('1.jpg')

    canvas = Canvas(self.root, width=300, height=300)
    canvas.pack()

    im = Image.open(self.path.get()) 
    canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

    l = tkinter.Label(self.root,textvariable=self.s)
    l.pack()
    self.root.mainloop()


app = MyTkApp()
app.start()
```

When I run it, everything works fine, until I include:

```
app.s.set('test') # <--- works
app.path.set('2.jpg') # <--- does nothing :(
```

So I see the first image, I can also update the label, but I never see the new picture. This is probably because the garbage collection gets to it first :(

So ... can I just define the variable global? That kind of feels ... not right. What would you suggest? I would like to stick as close to my solution as possible, as the other code around it already works pretty well - but if there is a good reason not to, I'm always open to take a good advice.

Comment: app.s.set('test') # <--- works why does this work ? what happens ? to get a new image you _must_ do im = Image.open(self.path.get()) 
    canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)

Comment: I don't really underdstand what you are trying to tell me... My code changes the label when I call `app.s.set('test')` from Foo -> test. But my picture in the canvas is not changed when I call `app.path.set('2.jpg')`. Does that answer your question, or did you mean sth else?

Comment: as far as I can tell you just deleted one line after `canvas.image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)`, which was `canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=canvas.image)` when you edited my post. I also tried your code, but didn't have success. Can you tell my why you did that and what you wanted to show?